# Warning message when moving GUI window using mouse

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

I am starting to get this warning message while trying to move GUI window using mouse around screen.  This only happened after upgrading to PYQT5,  issues did not happen in PYQT4:

**D pid(26812) tid(27528) 18:13:54 EdgeSnapFeature::PostExitSizeMove: WM_TWINVIEW_SHOW_GRIDLINES -> off**

Any idea what is causing this issue?  Web search did not give any clues.

Comment: It seems a warning from the window system, if it doesn't cause any issue and the program still works you can probably ignore it.

Comment: @musicamante.  Yes, that is my inclination. Just trying to understand why it only happened after upgrading to PYQT5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is related to the Nvidia Quadro series cards. I noticed the same issue and tracked it to the Quadro View application that helps to arrange your screens. Since I do not rely on Quadro View I simply disabled it by going into all apps and opening Quadro View and there is a disable Quadro View button on the top left.

[image]